# sklearn report formating lost in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I'm pretty new to coding (in a bootcamp for data science) and recently decided to check out VSCode as an IDE. It's been pretty nice so far, but I've noticed that cell output formatting is lost when printing things like sklearn reports. I've tried searching for a fix to this but I'm guessing I don't know what the correct search terms are. Can anyone assist?

[vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKcI1.jpg)
[jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7lyW.jpg)

[vscnoprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRUW3.jpg)

Comment: is it the same if you remove the print() or use display?

Comment: it changes the output to match juputer but doesn't process the line breaks. pic added to original post

Comment: Can you describe your problem in detail?
What are your requirements for output content?
Why do I get different content when I open the first of the two pictures you uploaded twice.

Comment: the first picture shows cell output format when run in VSCode, the second shows cell output in jupyter notebook (expected)

I'm not sure why they don't match - I want VSCode to have the same output format as jupyter.

the third image shows cell output in VSCode if I remove the print statement - it looks closer but doesn't register the newlines -  \n

Comment: @James Goudreault Have you downloaded the extension of jupyter? It can also take effect in vscode

Comment: Yes I have Jupyter and Jupyter Keymap extensions installed.